# Call Ajax using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I want to crawl web page, this page has a download button, when I press it current page show me download progress in title and then show me download link which can be pressed. I think its done via Ajax because I can see some in `developer console -> Network ->XHR`

This my code to crawl site

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://9xbuddy.com/process?url=https://www.fembed.com/v/6mv22g3qfsdfsd");
        //  final ScriptResult scriptResult = page.executeJavaScript("beacon.js");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);
```

But this code return me page which I get after button click and don't load Ajax. I know which Ajax requests were made by site, is it any way to manually call Ajax requests?

Comment: There is a way. You should capture the traffic and then reconstruct it. Are you familiar with how HTTP works?

Comment: @Arya Thank for response, Yes I'm familir with http , but in official site of HtmlUnit I found only examples with NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController and waitForBackgroundJavaScript to load S with Ajax and this not solve my problem

Comment: Have you captured the traffic to know the URL and parameters needed?

Comment: In developer console I have seen 4 POST Ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the Ajax calls manually with HtmlUnit, if you find that the Google Chrome console is not sufficient, you can use a tool such as Fiddler. Once you have identified the HTTP call, you can reconstruct it with HTMLUnit like below

```
URL url = new URL(
        "http://tws.target.com/searchservice/item/search_results/v1/by_keyword?callback=getPlpResponse&navigation=true&category=55krw&searchTerm=&view_type=medium&sort_by=bestselling&faceted_value=&offset=60&pageCount=60&response_group=Items&isLeaf=true&parent_category_id=55kug&custom_price=false&min_price=from&max_price=to");
WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.GET);

requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept", "*/*");
requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Referer", "http://www.target.com/c/xbox-one-games-video/-/N-55krw");
requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
requestSettings.setAdditionalHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);

System.out.println(page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
```